# How to zip a folder of 30 gb in Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003

How to zip a folder of 30 gb in Windows 2003 server

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using winrar. www.rarsoft.com

With this you can split the files into decent size chunks of 500MB/1GB each and also you can just store the data which will be much faster than compressing it, however you won't save on any file size.

[image: Winrar]

Comment: I actually still use 700MB chunks, because they fit nicely on a 4.2GB DVD anyway :-) Also, with (Win)RAR you can add recovery records: they work in a similar fashion to (Quick)PAR.

Answer (score 2):

I would use 7-Zip and use the 7z zip format as it is compressied less but has a smaller file size.

Answer (score 0):

In any recent Windows edition explorer supports zip files natively - just select the files/directories you want, right-click, and select "compressed (zipped) folder" from the "Send To" menu.

This always creates the archive in the current directory, which might be an issue if the area is on a filesystem with little free space or is readonly to your user. On XP and 2003 there is a 2Gb limit on the size of the archive file which might be a problem depending what your 30Gb of data is. 30Gb of web server log files would easily compress into less than 2Gb for instance, but a 30Gb database backup almost certainly wouldn't. Vista/2008/7 do not have this size limit, *but* be aware that large archives created on Vista/2008/7 this way are not compatible with the older software.

If the data does not compress to less than 2Gb or you need to compress to a different location then you'll need a 3rd party tool. I usually recommend the open source [7zip](http://7-zip.org/) as suggested by Benny - it supports most common compression formats, compresses much better (though significantly slower) in its own format, supports large archives, supports creating the archive in any arbitrary location, and various other options.

Comment: "30Gb database backup almost certainly wouldn't" - depends on the structure of your database. We've got an ollllld SQL database that uses char() everywhere (rather than varchar()) and it compresses brilliantly. A 15Gb data file zips up to about 120Mb.